# TypeError: list of indices must be integers, not str

Tags: python, python-3.3

What is wrong in my code to give me the error:
    TypeError: List of indices must be integers, not str

Here is my code:

```
print("This programe will keep track of your TV schedule.")
Finish = False
Show = []
ShowStart = []
ShowEnd = []
while not Finish:
print()
ShowName = input("What is the shows name?: ")
if ShowName == "":
    Finish = True
else:
    ShowStartTime = input("What time does the show start?: ")
    ShowEndTime = input("What time does the show end?: ")
    Show.append(ShowName)
    ShowStart.append(ShowStartTime)
    ShowEnd.append(ShowEndTime)
print("{0:<10}  |  {1:<10}  |  {2:<10}  ".format("Show Name", "Start Time", "End Time"))
for each in Show:
print("{0:<10}  |  {1:<10}  |  {2:<10}  ".format(Show[each], ShowStart[each],  ShowEnd[each]))
input()
```

Comment: When you googled "TypeError: List of indices must be integers, not str" - what didn't help you / what didn't you understand from the results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your last loop is wrong. Try this:

```
for each in range(len(Show)):
    print("{0:<10}  |  {1:<10}  |  {2:<10}  ".format(Show[each], ShowStart[each],  ShowEnd[each]))
```

(Your 3 lists should be merged in one list of dictionary by the way:

```
print("This programe will keep track of your TV schedule.")
Finish = False
shows = []
while not Finish:
    ShowName = input("What is the shows name?: ")
    if ShowName == "":
        Finish = True
    else:
        ShowStartTime = input("What time does the show start?: ")
        ShowEndTime = input("What time does the show end?: ")
        shows.append({'name': ShowName, 'start': ShowStartTime, 'end': ShowEndTime})

print("{0:<10}  |  {1:<10}  |  {2:<10}  ".format("Show Name", "Start Time", "End Time"))

for item in shows:
    print("{0:<10}  |  {1:<10}  |  {2:<10}  ".format(item['name'], item['start'],  item['end']))
    # Or  the more pythonic way:
    print("{name:<10} | {start:<10} | {end:<10} ".format(**item)
input()
```

)

Comment: If you're going to use a `dict`, it'd be nicer to use named parameters such as: `print("{name:<10}  |  {start:<10}  |  {end:<10}  ".format(**item)` instead

Comment: Yea of course, but I didn't want to complexify the code too much (I don't think the author know the `**var` syntax yet :-) ). I add your solution as an alternative.

Comment: Thanks really cleared this up for me, I also have learn that new item stuff thanks. I'm kind of a noob which I am sure you guessed :D