# KeyError: 'Name' , What's the issue?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Can anyone tell me why I am getting this error? I see no issue with the code, when I replace `**item` with `Name,Start,End` I still can't get it to work

```
print("To finish input enter nothing.")
Schedule = []
Finish = False
while not Finish:
    Name = input("What is the name of the show?: ")
    Start = input("What time does the show start?: ")
    End = input("What time does the show end?: ")
    Schedule.append({'Name':Name, 'Start':Start, 'End':End})
    print("{0:<10}  |  {1:<10}  -  {2:<10}".format(Name,Start,End))
    print("{Name:<10}  |  {Start:<10}  -  {End:<10}  ".format(**item))
    if len(Name) == 0 or len(Start) == 0 or len(End) == 0:
        Finish = True
```

Comment: I noticed that there is a problem with the indentation.

Comment: This is just due to my formatting on the website it is OK in the actual source.

Comment: Since you didn't show us the complete error and traceback, I will assume there is in fact no error.

Comment: Just to note: This appears to be related to an issues whereby the OP has not used the code correctly from the previous answer on: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18075476/typeerror-list-of-indices-must-be-integers-not-str

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never create `item`.

```
item = {'Name':Name, 'Start':Start, 'End':End}
Schedule.append(item)
```

Comment: Thank you, I have only just learnt about items so I was not too sure how they worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
print("To finish input enter nothing.")
Schedule = []
Finish = False
while not Finish:
    Name = raw_input("What is the name of the show?: ")
    Start = raw_input("What time does the show start?: ")
    End = raw_input("What time does the show end?: ")
    Schedule.append({'Name':Name, 'Start':Start, 'End':End})
    print("{0:<10}  |  {1:<10}  -  {2:<10}".format    (Name,Start,End))
    print("{Name:<10}  |  {Start:<10}  -  {End:<10}  ".format    (**item))
    if len(Name) == 0 or len(Start) == 0 or len(End) == 0:
        Finish = True
```

Comment: I'm in python 3, I don't think raw_input is needed and it does not work if I do use raw input.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I tried it in Python 2.7 and that change made the code work. I thought it could help you too...

Answer (score 0):

```
print("{Name:<10}  |  {Start:<10}  -  {End:<10}  ".format(**item))
```

This code works fine for me except that you don't have item defined?

Assuming that item is some sort of container like (Name, Start, End) you need to change this line to either this:

```
print("{:<10}  |  {:<10}  -  {:<10}  ".format(**item))
```

So that you aren't using keys and it can just fill the fields in order.
Or:

```
print("{Name:<10}  |  {Start:<10}  -  {End:<10}  ".format(Name=item[0],
                                                          Start=item[1],
                                                          End=item[2]))
```

If you really intend on using keys.

Basically your key error is coming from requesting values with a key ({**Name**:<10}) when you haven't supplied a value for that key.

Hope that helps.